# What does "ImportError: cannot import name randbits" mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, import, importerror

The first cell of my jupyter notebook contains the libraries I want to import.  For some reason when I run it receive the `ImportError: cannot import name randbits`.  I have never seen this import error before and have already tried restarting the kernel and confirmed that all libraries were installed correctly.  As anyone seen this before and know what to do about this error?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import xlsxwriter 
import math

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import requests

File C:\pyver\py3.10.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:151, in <module>
    149 from . import fft
    150 from . import polynomial
--> 151 from . import random
    152 from . import ctypeslib
    153 from . import ma

File C:\pyver\py3.10.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py:180, in <module>
    126 __all__ = [
    127     'beta',
    128     'binomial',
   (...)
    176     'zipf',
    177 ]
    179 # add these for module-freeze analysis (like PyInstaller)
--> 180 from . import _pickle
    181 from . import _common
    182 from . import _bounded_integers

File C:\pyver\py3.10.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pickle.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from .mtrand import RandomState
      2 from ._philox import Philox
      3 from ._pcg64 import PCG64, PCG64DXSM

File mtrand.pyx:1, in init numpy.random.mtrand()

File bit_generator.pyx:38, in init numpy.random.bit_generator()

ImportError: cannot import name randbits
```

Answer (score 64):

I have been having the same issue all day. Finally figured out what solved my problem. Somehow anaconda3/Lib/secrets.py got overwritten. Numpy relies on files in this directory called random.py and secrets.py so if you have files with those names numpy will not load.

- I renamed my incorrect secrets.py file
- Found the secrets.py source code and recreated the file. Solved my issue.

The links below were the most beneficial for me:

People having similar issues with numpy:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14860

Source code for secrets.py:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/secrets.py

Comment: Your solution is a life saver! I uplaoded a secrets.py file and once I removed the file it worked.

Comment: YES! I created a "secrets.py" file in my project and that messed this up. I wish python had a namespace collision detector.

Comment: fyip..in my case was getting error `ImportError: cannot import name randbits` , and when looked for ```secrets.py``` it was for another package Bokeh, i had to rename their secrets.py files. I know i broke bokeh for now but this was a quick way for me to get pandas to work!

Comment: exactly same problem with openai module....

Comment: Thank you ! I would have never found out without this. 
Had to refractor my sectrets.py in my project to secrets2.py and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

I actually added a file called `secrets.py` to the folder I was working in and it caused the problem. After renaming the file the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Rename any file or package called "secrets.py" or "secrets".

For example, this project gives problems.

```
project/
|-- main.py
|-- secrets/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- random_name.py
```

While this does not

```
project/
|-- main.py
|-- secret_files/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- random_name.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked when I renamed from secrets.py to mysecrets.py

Comment: This answer was already given by others. Please make sure that you're not repeating existing answers when answering older questions.

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me because I made a file called secrets.py, I wasn't even using it or importing it anywhere, it just contained an api key that I was not using yet.

Yet having it caused the same error as you, I renamed it 'the_secrets.py" and now it works.

crazy

Answer (score 0):

You can just add that line `SOME_API='abcdefg'` into the secrets.py source file and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

it was working, until tried to call the script from **SSIS**, It works for me after changed my **secrets.py**  to something else.

so change **secrets.py** in your project to something like **credentials_prod.py**

**Tips:** *Try not using any generic name for your files, functions and packages in general*