# numpy import error with python + jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

### I get the following import erorr when I try import numpy into my jupyter notebook project:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import requests

File ~/Downloads/algorithmic-trading-python-master/myenv /lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:152
    150 from . import fft
    151 from . import polynomial
--> 152 from . import random
    153 from . import ctypeslib
    154 from . import ma

File ~/Downloads/algorithmic-trading-python-master/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py:180
    126 __all__ = [
    127     'beta',
    128     'binomial',
   (...)
    176     'zipf',
    177 ]
    179 # add these for module-freeze analysis (like PyInstaller)
--> 180 from . import _pickle
    181 from . import _common
    182 from . import _bounded_integers

File ~/Downloads/algorithmic-trading-python-master/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py:1
----> 1 from .mtrand import RandomState
      2 from ._philox import Philox
      3 from ._pcg64 import PCG64, PCG64DXSM

File mtrand.pyx:1, in init numpy.random.mtrand()

File bit_generator.pyx:38, in init numpy.random.bit_generator()

ImportError: cannot import name randbits
```

I've tried reinstalling python and numpy, and reseting the virtual environment, etc but nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: Would this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055157/what-does-importerror-cannot-import-name-randbits-mean) your question? A user had the same `ImportError` as you, and the resolution was to reset their `secrets.py` file, which can get overwritten.

Comment: @ndhulipala yes I seemed to have had the same problem, thanks a lot!