# How can I fix this recurring Numpy import error

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, importerror

I'm Following along with an online algorithmic trading course in Python using PyCharm but an error message keeps occurring when : try to import numpy.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import xlsxwriter
import math
from secrets import IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN

stocks = pd.read_csv('sp_500_stocks.csv')

symbol = 'AAPL'
api_url = f"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stock/{symbol}/quote"
print(api_url)
```

But there is always an error message saying:

```
File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
  File "bit_generator.pyx", line 38, in init numpy.random.bit_generator
ImportError: cannot import name randbits
```

Can anyone help to fix this?

I've already tried updating and reinstalling Python, Numpy and Pycharm. but the error is persistent.

I've also tried the rest of my code on its own which works fine.

Comment: Do you have a random.py or secrets.py file in your project directory? You might've ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055157/what-does-importerror-cannot-import-name-randbits-mean)